# How long does a money transfer from Göttingen, Germany to India take, and how can I find what the hold-up is?

Tags: india, international-transfer, germany

I have transferred Money from my friends account to my Indian account as i was not having my own account at göttingen, Germany.
It has been more than 20 days but I have not received the amount in my Indian account.
Please help how Long will it take.
I have also called contacted customer care and they said that i have to pay 50 to 100 euros to know where my Money is stuck.
Is there any other way by which i can come out all of this and track my Money.
thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are being scammed. Who is this "Friend", and why are they giving you money?

Comment: And who at 'customer care' did you contact? If you google that company's name, does it show you a different telephone number than the one you were provided?

Comment: _You_ transferred money from your _friend's account_ to _your_ account in India? Your friend authorized you to do this, e.g. by giving you his/her password, so that you could do the money transfer on your own? Since you have access to your friend's account, have you considered using the "Track My Money" facility offered by your friend's bank? Or just calling your friend who could get the information for you without you having to pay a fee? As Grade'Eh'Bacon says, it sounds like you are being scammed. What is surprising is that they are willing to settle for 100 euros.

Comment: 'Transfer' is very generic. Was it a _Wire Transfer_? It should be done in one business day. Was it a mailed check? Or what?

Comment: Ask your friend to ask his bank what happened to the money. For him as the account owner that should be free of charge. You can go to the bank with him. If he is a real friend and the bank messed up (or it's just a slow process for whatever reason) then he'll do that with you and help you sort this out. If he isn't willing to do that then the answers about being scammed apply.

Answer (score 5):

You should NEVER have to pay a fee to find out what has happened to a transaction in progress. You might sometimes have to pay for duplicate copies of a statement or similar, but not just to find out what is going on.

It sounds like you are being scammed - your "friend" tells you they have transferred you money (but they have not done anything in reality), then they give you a "customer care number" to call and try to get you to pay them money in order to find out what has happened to the (non-existent) transaction.

If you think this is plausibly what is happening - for example, if you google the company who is supposedly doing the transfer and find that they do not exist, or that the number you have been given is not really their customer care line - then you should cease all contact with your "friend" and pass all communications to your local law enforcement.